# How to connect to SQL managed instance on private endpoint on different VNET

Tags: sql-server, azure

I can't connect to SQL managed instance from Azure VM in different VNET.

VM network VNET address space:10.0.0.0/16
VM subnet: 10.0.1.0/24

SQL instance VNET address space:10.0.0.0/16
SQL instance subnet: 10.0.0.0/24

On SQL instance subnet NSG allows traffic from anywhere on port 1433, destination SQL instance subnet: 10.0.0.0/24.

From VM on 10.0.1.0/24 subnet cannot telnet to SQL managed instance on port 1433.

```
telnet sqlinstance.xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net 1433
Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed
```

I tried to create a private link on SQL managed instance subnet, but wizard shows error "the selected subnet has a delegation and cannot be used with a private endpoint".

I can access on public endpoint without issues.

Comment: Hello @overflowed
The Azure SQL Managed Instance mandatory inbound security rules require management ports 9000, 9003, 1438, 1440, and 1452 to be open from Any source on the Network Security Group (NSG) that protects SQL Managed Instance. Although these ports are open at the NSG level, they are protected at the network level by the built-in firewall.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/management-endpoint-verify-built-in-firewall

Comment: thanks @OlegShalnov, but i can access on public endpoint on port 1433

Comment: Add the output of `nslookup sqlinstance.xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net` to verify IP address resolution.    And are you really trying to connect from a different VNET with an overlapping address space (which shouldn't work), or from a different subnet in the same VNET (which should work without additional configuration)?

Comment: Sorry for not replying before, different network, overlapping addresses, no wonder why connection fail, output is "weird" address 10.0.0.254